# SIGABRT with Editing Tables - IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, sigabrt

I have got the following code:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:   (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [[delegate contentArray] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [self.tableView reloadData];
}
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
}
}
```

Now when I run it, the edit button works and the delete interface comes up, but I get a SIGABRT error when I press the delete button.

I am not sure how to read the log files yet, but if you need them, tell me how to get them to you:-)

EDIT:

I have posted the console log here:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 41600.
2011-12-15 14:35:31.932 OrderList[41600:b903] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView     _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:995
2011-12-15 14:35:32.227 OrderList[41600:b903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of    rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4)  must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fd55a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01129313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00f8def8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
3   Foundation                          0x008173bb -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
4   UIKit                               0x00092e8b -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 8420
5   UIKit                               0x00081cf8 -[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:] + 56
6   OrderList                           0x00002546 -[RootViewController tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:] + 166
7   UIKit                               0x0007f037 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 101
8   UIKit                               0x000144fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
9   UIKit                               0x000a4799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
10  UIKit                               0x000a6c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
11  UIKit                               0x000a57d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
12  UIKit                               0x00038ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
13  UIKit                               0x00019c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
14  UIKit                               0x0001ef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
15  GraphicsServices                    0x00cd6992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00fb6944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00f16cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00f13f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00f13840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00f13761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
21  GraphicsServices                    0x00cd51c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
22  GraphicsServices                    0x00cd5289 GSEventRun + 115
23  UIKit                               0x00022c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
24  OrderList                           0x00001bcd main + 125
25  OrderList                           0x00001b45 start + 53
    )
    terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)
```

--Jeff

Comment: Please post what is in the Xcode console. There is highly likely to be an exception thrown which will show up there. My guess is that you need to wrap what you have where it deletes the row in a `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]` and lose the `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: If you are running this on Simulator and using XCode4 you should see debug console XCode Menu -> View -> Debug Area -> Active console. See why it crashed with SIGABRT. Posting debug information helps us pinpoint to what caused issue instead of taking vague guesses. To guess from your code you might be removing objects from immutable array ( NSArray is immutable Array, NSMutableArray is mutable array). [delegate contentArray] might be immutable Array. This is a guess why your app might have crashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key line from the log:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught  exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of    rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4)  must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

mattjgalloway is 100% correct about the solution. I hope he posts that as an answer so that he can get credit for it.

Comment: Cool cheers for the answer - I'll save the credit for him as per your request.